# Change direction of mat-tree UI line border bottom issue design angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, sass

mat tree changes direction from right to left. The bottom border needs to be removed refer to the Image
[image] https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-tree-nested-sndfhl?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open your tree items than your current css effecting, Please add below scss in `styles.scss`

```
mat-nested-tree-node{
  &[aria-expanded="true"]{
   & > li {
          border-bottom: none;
      }
  }
}
```

or simply add below css in your component's `.css` file

```
mat-nested-tree-node[aria-expanded="true"] > li {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

For solve your problem I have added the below new css class:

```
li.example-tree-container {
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

In the below css class I have made the border 2px. this class already exist in your stylesheet please find it and make 2px border size.

```
li[_ngcontent-c0] ul[_ngcontent-c0]{
  border-top: 2px dotted gray; 
}
```